# Realize the subscription of different messages

Tags: java

I have many kinds of messages to be sent and the user can subscribe to some of them.

I plan to use binary and & set operation to decide whether messages to be sent.

for example:

there are three messages: message A message B and message C

if someone subscribe all of them, the binary number is 111 for this user. Now a message A will be sent(100) and  I will use this number(100) & 111. if I don`t get a zero, I will send it to the use.

```
public class TestBinary {

    static final int USER_DEFINED_NUM = 7; // 111
    static final int REQUEST_NUM = 8;      //1000

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean result = (USER_DEFINED_NUM & REQUEST_NUM) != 0;
       if(result) {
           System.out.println("send");
       } else {
           System.out.println("not send");
       }
    }
}
```

This method will fail, if there are more than 32 kinds of messages, because the int type can only represent 32 message types.

Do you have better way? thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `long` to handle up to 64 messages with this strategy. But this pattern is (only) useful if you want to allow combinations of messages, like you have messages that are of type `A` and `C` (which would make in a `101` type).

If you need this pattern and want to *flag* much more then 32/64 messages (message types), consider using an `boolean` array:

```
boolean[] flags = new boolean[MAX_NUMBER_OF_FLAGS];
```

---

If you need to store the *subscription vector* in a database, then you can *stringify* the field. Define two chars for true and false, and store:

```
 "-----*-*"
```

(if you have 8 messages and the users subscribes to messages 1 (A)  and 3 (C)). This can be stored to a `VARCHAR` type field.

Comment: In the first method I can use a column and value 4 to represent the subscription of message A. If use the following method how should  I design database table？